# Error in Unity project : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher')

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an android library project with resources and imported the library project in the Unity project here

> (F:\Unity\demoproject\testing\Testing\Assets\Plugins\Android)

When I am trying to build my project in Unity then I am getting the following error :-

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
F:\AndroidStudio\AndroidStudioSDK\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "F:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudioSDK/sdk/platforms/android-22\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').

AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)
 xhdpi-v4

Files:
  drawable\app_banner.png
    Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
  drawable\app_icon.png
    Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
  values\strings.xml
    Src: () res\values\strings.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\app_banner.png
      Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
    drawable\app_icon.png
      Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
  Type values
    values\strings.xml
      Src: () res\values\strings.xml
Including resources from package: F:\AndroidStudio\AndroidStudioSDK\sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
Processing image: res\drawable\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable\app_icon.png: 94% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
    (new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_banner.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
]
```

Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testinglib"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

             <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Script File In Unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Freeb : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    public void OnGUI(){

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (50, 50, 100, 100), "Open")) {
            //AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

            AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
            currentActivity.Call ("createMethod", currentActivity);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check "ic_launcher" in ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi
- Try to make a folder "drawable" and put in it "ic_launcher"
- **@style/AppTheme** not visible in the screenshot. Try to remove `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: I have tried, but still having same issue. Kindly help us more !